# How can I use "How many" in a question without using helping verb?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

How can I use "How many" in a question without using helping verb?
Like this

> How many people died?

Answer (score 1):

When the expected answer has a number in the subject, there is no inversion or helping verb.

If you want an answer like "Five people died" you ask "How many people died?"

If you want an answer like "He killed five people" you ask "How many people did he kill?"

If you want an answer like "There are five dead people" you ask "How many dead people are there?"